# Docker container IP's not communicating in kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking

I have a kubenetes cluster running successfully. I have tried bringing applications in the cluster like a simple nginx. I have a setup of master-minion and a minion node.

The problem here is that I'm able to launch applications from the master-minion node but when I bring up applications in another minion it gives me an error as no route to host.

After some exploration I saw that container ip is not pingable from the master-minion node.

Can someone point out as to what to do to fix this communication between containers in the cluster?

Comment: Need a bit more info to understand your problem. What platform are you running on? What do you mean by master-minion? Are you running master components and kubelet on the same host? Can you paste the output of `kubectl version` and `kubectl get componentstatuses`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up networking for kubernetes? you can refer to:
http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/admin/networking.html